# Convergence of $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi tn^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I've been interested in reading about the Jacobi Theta Functions and wanted to prove the functional equation $\theta(t^{-1})=\sqrt{t}\theta(t)$ where $\theta(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi tn^2}$ and $t>0$. My first question is to prove that this sum converges absolutely. Are there any tricks to showing this? My intuition is that because the summand converges so fast to 0 that it's almost obvious that it converges. However, I don't necessarily see a way to prove it analytically.

Also, any decent reading material about these types of functional equations would be great. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hint: $e^{-x}<\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while the intuition you described is enough.

But if you want some detail, we can separate out the term $n=0$. The rest is twice $\sum_1^\infty e^{-\pi t n^2}$.

Now observe  that for positive  $n$ we have $e^{-\pi tn^2}\le e^{-\pi tn}$. The series $\sum_1^\infty e^{-\pi t n}$ is a geometric series with positive common ratio less than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had an inkling that it was this simple.

Comment: You are welcome. Your post basically said it was this simple. You had an implicit comparison in mind ("goes so fast to $0$). The above answer just makes that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

For $t>0$ and $n\ne0$ we have $\exp (\pi t n^2)>1/0!+\pi t n^2/1!>\pi t n^2$ so $0<\exp (-\pi t n^2)<1/\pi t n^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the functional equation, it can be proved with the Poisson Summation Formula and the fact that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian.